# Find third degree polynomial with real coefficients so that $P(1-i)=2+i$ and $P(i)=1-2i$

Tags: polynomials

Find third degree polynomial with real coefficients so that $P(1-i)=2+i$ and $P(i)=1-2i$

$P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

How to find $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that

\begin{align}
i^2 &= -1 \\
i^3 &= -i
\end{align}

And

\begin{align}
(1-i)^2 &= (1-i)\cdot(1-i)=1-2i+i^2=-2i \\
(1-i)^3 &= (1-i)\cdot(-2i)=-2i+2i^2=-2i-2
\end{align}

Then by substitution you will have four equations

$(1)\,\,d-b=1$

$(2)\,\,c-a=-2$

$(3)\,\,c+d-2a=2$

$(4)\,\,-2a-2b-c=1$

Use $(2)$ and $(3)$ together to get $d$ in terms of $a$. Then use other equations to get $b$ and $c$ in terms of $a$. Then solve for $a$ in any of the four equations. Then solve for $b$, $c$, and $d$ using the relations that you found.

Comment: Let me suggest to delete the two lines involving $\sqrt{-1}$, which add nothing to the solution but only use a disputable notation.

Answer (score 1):

Write out $P(i)=1-2i$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$. Separate the real and the imaginary parts of that equation to get two equations (you can do this since you know that the coefficients are real). Do the same with $P(1-i)$. You should now have four linear equations that with some luck can be solved.

Comment: Dividing $P(x)$ with $i$ gives $-i(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$ but $P(i)=1-2i$. What happens with the real part?

Comment: Who said about dividing? $P(i) = (d-b)+i(c-a)=1-2i$.

Comment: @display_error I said nothing about division. I said to _separate_ the real and imaginary parts. For instance, if you had had the equation $x+yi=1+i$, and you wanted real solutions for $x$ and $y$, then it would be straight-forward to solve the equation because the real part ($x=1$) and the imaginary part ($yi =i$) are independent. In your case, the equations might _look_ a bit different, but the same trick works nicely.